# Sqoop command not found when running through Oozie

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

When I am running Sqoop script in CLI, it is running fine without any issue. But when run it using Oozie, it failed with Sqoop command not found. It seems sqoop is not installed in other data nodes. So to run Sqoop script using Oozie, sqoop should be installed in all data nodes or is there any alternatives for that. Currently we have one master and 2 Data nodes.

Comment: The Sqoop project was retired nearly a year ago (https://attic.apache.org/projects/sqoop.html) and Oozie hasn't had a release since 2019. Are you sure these are the tools you want to use?

Comment: I am runing it in EMR cluster version 5.34. There it hasn't retired. May be they forgot :) . But I need solution.

Comment: EMR should install it on every resource manager, if you've configured it correctly. Amazon support would know more than us